# Google Plus API Sign-in Query 20 Millions Quota

Tags: api, google-api, web-crawler, google-plus, quota

So, Google Plus promised 20 million of requests per day for sign-in queries. I currently only get 20000 query per day. I don't understand what is the difference between normal query and sign-in query. Can anybody explain?

Thanks,
Ami

[image: Google Plus API Quota]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods that are allowed by the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope, such as people.get and people.list, count against the "Sign-in queries" quota. All others count against the general "Queries" quota. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/#quota) for details.